# How to pass file-path with slashes to Windows Installer CreateService

Tags: postgresql, wix, windows-installer

I'm using Windows Installer's CreateService to create PostgreSQL service. WiX Source is as follows:

```
<ServiceInstall 
    Id="InstallService_0001" 
    Name="my_pg_svc" 
    DisplayName="My Postgres Service" 
    Description="Database Server " 
    Start="auto" 
    ErrorControl="normal" 
    Arguments="runservice -N "my_pg_svc" -D "[DATA_FOLDER_PATH]" -w" 
    Type="ownProcess" 
    Account="NT Authority\NetworkService"
/>
```

`pg_ctl.exe` requires path with slashes (e.g.: `D:/my_proj/my_db`), however Windows Installer replaces [DATA_FOLDER_PATH] with path with backslashes (e.g.: `D:\my_proj\my_db`).

The question is how can I make WI pass the path in format I need, or, alternatively how can I make `pg_ctl.exe` accept path in said format?

P.S. Adding `PGDATA` environment variable and omitting the path parameter is not an option, since end-user might already be using that envvar.